# Cron job not working in hostgator hosting

Tags: cron

I try to run a file at a particular time every day so for this I setup Cron job in my Hostgator hosting for this I use this command

```
10  17  *   *   *   /opt/php54/bin/php /home/myusername/public_html/test/email.php
```

but am not getting any email at 17:10 pm where am wrong anyone help me out for this ??

Comment: Your Cronjob is correct. But are you sure '/opt/php54/bin/php' is the correct path? 
First thing to check: is php sentmail enabled? Does your php-script work running manually?

Comment: yes when I reload that page we get email I try this one too 

10 17 * * * php /home/kanpurma/public_html/zoo/email.php


but don't know my Hostgator server I think US server and we are here in India we get mail in the night 
at 9.45pm and am setting time 10.10 in 24 hr format is time zone affect this?